# What does walking on wet pavement sound like?

Tags: single-word-requests, onomatopoeia

I've had the word 'clicking' down for a while, but it truly doesn't capture what I'm trying to express. I have a very distinct sound in my head, but I just can't find the right word. I would just leave it and move on, but it's bugging me to the point that I can no longer push it aside. Can someone help?
(Clarification: the character is walking in non-athletic, typical teenager sneakers; not boots, or heels, or anything that would make a clicking sound.)

Comment: wet pavement make an unsticking sound when you lift your foot off of it, more than any sound from treading on it, unless there are puddles that splat.

Comment: It depends greatly on the nature of the pavement, and how wet.

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks . try to find out whether it's asphalt or concrete, then how porous the surface is. if it's porous and warm, and no water accumulating, maybe you hear nothing. the water prevents the usual sound of dust grinding under the show.

Comment: @jlovegren It's a city sidewalk; smooth concrete.  The rain has only just begun, but the entire day has been heavy and misty. Cool weather. Not too hot, not too cold.  There most likely aren't any deep puddles on the surface, though perhaps a thin layer of water?

Comment: then it is like a soft clap.

Comment: In general, I would say it makes no sound, at least not unless it’s not just wet but covered in puddles (in which case it makes a _splashing_ sound). Could you try to describe the sound you’re thinking of in more detail, or even better find a sound clip of it?

Answer (score 1):

[squelch](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/squelch) [ODOL]

> verb
>   [no object]
>   **1** Make a soft sucking sound such as that made by treading heavily through mud.
>   ‘bedraggled guests squelched across the lawns’

(ibid.)

> '… I swear as I was walking about in Williton today I could almost feel the pavement squelching underfoot, as if the water has crept up and is laying directly underneath.’